# Processing a ConcurrentBag shows over 5000 tasks when only 2 items in bag

Tags: c#

Found the following ConcurrentBag example on Microsoft [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.concurrentbag-1?view=netframework-4.8).

I was debugging a unit test and kind of inspecting around and the bagConsumeTasks had over 5000 items in it. Is this normal? The bag had only 2 itmes.

[image]

```
HashSet<string> x = new HashSet<string>();
List<Task> bagConsumeTasks = new List<Task>();
int itemsInBag = 0;
while (!result.IsEmpty)
{
    bagConsumeTasks.Add(Task.Run(() =>
    {
        string item;
        if (result.TryTake(out item))
        {
            x.Add(item);
            itemsInBag++;
        }
    }));
}
Task.WaitAll(bagConsumeTasks.ToArray());
```

Comment: That is a peculiar example. Somewhere out there this has been copy-pasted into production code.

Comment: That is not a great example.  There will be thousands of tasks started that get a false return from cb.TryTake().  That only stops after 500 of them managed to run and empty the bag.  Well, one way to measure how many processor cores the machine has :)  Microsoft invested enormous resources in the MSDN docs and examples but that petered out after .NET 2.0

Answer (score 2):

There's a race between checking `result.IsEmpty` and the tasks consuming items, leading the code to start more tasks than needed.

The increment of local variable `itemsInBag` by many tasks in parallel is also a race, but mitigated by the call to `Console.WriteLine` just before it.

While in some cases this could be a bug, I guess the over-scheduling of tasks may be deliberate here, to demonstrate the class running under high contention?

Because nothing else is using the concurrent bag, the example could just create a fixed number of Tasks:

```
    List<Task> bagConsumeTasks = new List<Task>();
    int itemsInBag = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 500; i++)
    {
        bagConsumeTasks.Add(Task.Run(() =>
        {
            int item;
            if (cb.TryTake(out item))
            {
                Console.WriteLine(item);
                Interlocked.Increment(ref itemsInBag);
            }
        }));
    }
    Task.WaitAll(bagConsumeTasks.ToArray());
```